# How to change the color of certain parts of code in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, themes, customization

I use Android Studio with Material Theme, as it makes it look A LOT better. The only problem is that when I initialize a variable, it shows up as dark grey, which is pretty unreadable because I use the dark theme. Is there an option that I can change only that dark grey to some other color, without making any changes to the color of other pieces of code?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > The language for which you want to change the color